# Kotlin - how to iterate over a map or a list inside a builder block

Tags: kotlin

Probably is a dumb question but I would like to know if it's possible to iterate over a map or a list inside a builder block?

I'm building `HttpRequest` and I would like to work on top of a List or a Map of headers. As example, let's imagine this scenario:

```
val headers1 = hashMapOf("Content-type" to "application/json")
val headers2 = listOf("Content-type=application/json")
```

I really prefer to work with a Map instead of pass a list of `String=String` but I'm ok with that if it's simpler or more concise to read.

Here is how I'm building HttpRequest:

```
HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .uri(URI.create(endpoint))
    .method(method.value, HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
    .header(<inject headers here>)
    .build()
```

Is possible to add/inject headers in build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a map like this

```
val headers: Map<String, String> = /* ... */

HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
    .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .uri(URI.create(endpoint))
    .method(method.value, HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
    .apply {
        headers.forEach { (key, value) -> setRequestHeader(key, value) }
    }
```